What is this movie about aliens?
There was a movie that I saw a long time ago (not sure when), it was about aliens in the form of humans. I can't remember when it was filmed, it was in colour, fairly sure it was filmed in the USA. But this is all I remember from it:

There was a man, his head was mostly bald, though I can't remember what colour (and he was a taxi driver).
There was two kids (aliens) one boy and one girl, they looked like they were in their early teen years. 
The two alien kids I am fairly sure that they crashed landed on Earth and ended up in the USA.
The two kids found a man who the felt could help them, but by this time, it was either the FBI or CIA that was after the two alien kids.
The man mentioned above was asked by the two kids to drive them to an unknown location somewhere in the country side.
When they got in the car, the taxi driver asked them again where they wanted to go, but they said into the country side.
During the road trip, there was pursuing vehicles which belonged to either of these agencies which tried to stop the taxi.
The two kids (in the backseat of the taxi) started whispering about what to do when they found they were being followed and came to the conclusion they would crash the persuing vehicles.
The boy alien then suddenly disappeared (as if sinking into the backrest of the back seat) with a blue flash which almost looked like teleportation, was standing in the middle of the road and the following vehicles saw him.
The lead vehicle (obviously ruthless) decided to kill the alien boy, grinned savagely and sped up while the alien boy was standing facing towards the oncoming car.
The boy just stood there and then at an amazing rate of speed, the car smashed into the boy alien, the car was smashed to smithereens and the boy was still just standing there like nothing even happened. The other pursuing vehices backed off and drove away.
After this, either the taxi came back for him, the boy caught up to the car,  or the boy teleported back to the car.
When they reached this final location, the taxi driver asked the two kids for the required amount of cash, and the girl slapped an enormous wad of notes into his hand and the boy and girl climbed out.
When the two kids disappeared into a hut in the side of the road, the taxi driver was counting the money, and then he said:


Oh no, they overpaid

So after this happened, the man got out of the taxi and walked towards the wooden house and entered.

Meanwhile the girl the two aliens went into this place (I can't even remember how they got into it), and they started fighting off this monster alien inside (the place was full of ferns, trees and other shrub).
When they fought off the monster, they found a pod, reached into it and read the slip and it told them to trust the taxi driver. The boy objected but the girl said:


We have no choice, it's either we trust him or we are dead.


By this time, the taxi driver found out how to get into the place and found them in there. He had to fight off the monster as well. He found the two alien kids and they all fought their way out of the place to get back tot he taxi.
I think it was up to this part that the taxi driver found out that they were aliens.

This is all I remember from the movie, I really want to watch it again because it was a cool movie. Thanks guys, I really appreciate your help.

Race to Witch Mountain (2009)
Which is a remake of Escape to Witch Mountain (1975).

An alien spaceship crashes near Searchlight, Nevada, outside Las Vegas. Project Moon Dust, a secret Defense Department unit led by Henry Burke (Ciarán Hinds), arrives in black helicopters. Men in Black seize the ship and search for its passengers.
Jack Bruno (Dwayne Johnson) is a former mob get-away driver who drives a cab to avoid returning to jail.
When they arrive at an abandoned house, Bruno follows them out of concern and curiosity. The teenagers retrieve the device they were looking for within a hidden underground laboratory, but the three are attacked by a "Siphon" (Tom Woodruff, Jr.), a powerful armored alien assassin. The Siphon pursues the group until its spaceship crashes into a train and the creature is wounded. The three again escape Burke's agents, in part due to Sara's telepathy and telekinetics.
The teenagers explain to Bruno that they are from a dying planet 3,000 light years from Earth. Its government intends to invade Earth, despite the idea being unpopular among the majority of their race, so that their kind may survive. Seth and Sara's parents are scientists who sought a way to save their planet without invasion but were arrested before completing their experiment. The teenagers came to retrieve the successful results, but the alien government sent the assassin to stop them. To save both worlds, they must retrieve their spaceship and return home.

And so on.  You've essentially described the entire plot in your question. :-)

This is the exact movie, thanks man :), hahahaha yeah I know I described the whole plot, I tried to at least XD
